# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Только что сделал систему применение кодов, но по какой-то причине у меня отказывается работать забирание роли у пользователя. Если я поставлю отправку сообщения первым, то оно отправляется, но ошибка остается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
async def check_json():
    while True:
        with open("premium.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            if data["claimers"] != {}:
                for user in data["claimers"]:
                    if time.time() > data["claimers"][user]:
                        del data["claimers"][user]

                        member = await bot.get_or_fetch_user(user)
                        guild = bot.get_guild(1155525773424345151)
                        role = guild.get_role(1186708852767461416)

                        await member.remove_roles(role)
                        
                        await member.send(f"Hey! Your premium just expired. Thanks for using it :P")

                        with open("premium.json", "w") as f:
                            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
        f.close()

        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Простите, если вопрос тупой. Я просто не понимаю, в чем ошибка. Спасибо за уделенное время!

По запросу @Alpensin:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Alexander\Documents\code claimer.py", line 33, in on_ready
    await check_json()
  File "c:\Users\Alexander\Documents\code claimer.py", line 21, in check_json
    await member.remove_roles(role)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'remove_roles
```

Comment: А текст ошибки какой?

Comment: @Alpensin, сейчас обновлю вопрос с ошибкой.

Comment: Надо получать Member, а не User. Чтобы получить Member надо получить member после guild. member = await guild.get_member(user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо получать `Member`, а не `User`. Чтобы получить `Member` надо получить member после `guild`.

```py
member = guild.get_member(user)
```

Ссылка на метод - https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/api/guilds.html#disnake.Guild.get_member

Comment: Приветствую! Спасибо за ответ, но потребовалась небольшая правка *(убирание await)*. Уже запросил правку, в скором времени должны принять.

Comment: @ForevorBase, такие правки отклоняют как "попытки ответа", у вас достаточно репутации для комментирования.

Comment: @Alpensin, в документации данный метод не отмечен как асинхронный, `await` не нужен.